# Parse.com not able to import csv

Tags: csv, parse-platform

I need to import a csv file into Parse but unfortunately it doesn't work due to the fact that I have commas in the fields and also stuff like "€". This is how my test file looks like:

```
productname;productdescription;producturl;designer;category;price;pricecurrency;shipping;shippingcurrency
Materialmix-Shirt;SET2x36 2x38 2x40;http://some-url.com/artikel/materialmix-shirt-1.html;set;Longsleeves;39;"&euro;";4.9;"&euro;"
Kniestrümpfe FAMILY;Anziehen und wohlfühlen: Mit den beliebten Allround-Kniestrümpfen FAMILY von dummy gönnen Sie Ihren Füßen herrlichen Tragekomfort. Sie bestehen aus weicher, hautfreundlicher Baumwolle mit Elasthan-Anteil und überzeugen mit einer perfekten Passform.Weicher Griff Verstärkte Belastungszonen für optimale Haltbarkeit;http://some-url.com/artikel/family-3.html;dummy;Strümpfe & Socken;13;"&euro;";3.95;"&euro;"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: similar issue as dealing with http entities ...  its an encoding issue where you want to encapsulate your "string" in a json property that wont be parsed.. try looking at the equivalent http  https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution: Parse.com doesn't allow to use semicolon as separator. If I replace the semicolons with regular commas everything works fine.